# Does $P(Z = X + Y \leq z) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{z - x} f_{XY}(x, y) dydx $ always hold?

Tags: probability

Let $X, Y$ be continuous random variables defined in $[-\infty, +\infty]$, and $f_{XY}$ be their joint distribution. Define $Z = X + Y$.

Is it always true that
$$
P(Z \leq z) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{z - x} f_{XY}(x, y) dydx
$$

Or are there situations where this fails, and we have to resort to another approach, like convolutions?

Answer (score 1):

The event $X + Y \leq z$ is the set of outcomes $\{X=x,Y=y|x+y\leq z\}=\{X=x,Y=y|y\leq x-z\}$. You are integrating the joint density over the event, so your formula will always give the probability of the event.

Comment: What is the advantage of my approach using joint distributions over using convolutions? I thought convolutions in probability was invented for these kind of scenarios, but I've always seem to be able to solve the problems using just joint distributions.

Comment: Convolution gives the density of Z, but you have the CDF. Try taking the $z$-derivative of your double integral. You should get a convolution.